# P iff Q and P iff R, but not Q if R or R if Q

Tags: logic

I'm a total beginner with logic.

Something came up in a class of mine, and this statement was made:

```
A. It's P iff Q and P iff R, Q and R can never be true at the same time.
```

I'm under the impression that

```
B. (P iff Q) and (P iff R) => Q iff R
```

because hypothetical syllogism. Here was my "proof"

```
1. P iff Q => P if Q and Q if P
2. P iff R => P if R and R if P
3. P if Q and R if P => R if Q
4. P if R and Q if P => Q if R
5. R if Q and Q if R => Q iff R
```

Which one is correct, A, B, or something else, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you copied down the statement correctly?  Your reasoning is correct; iff is also transitive, which can be shown as you have by separating it into two if relations and considering them independently.  For the first statement to be true there must be a negation on one of the terms.